# Where is PHP's sybase_query Implemented?

Tags: php, sybase, php-extension

I want to look at the implementation of `sybase_query` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sybase-query.php) in PHP. How can I do that? I went here https://github.com/php/php-src, and searched for sybase_query, but nothing came up. Can you help me find the source to the sybase extension?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, it's an extension `sybase_ct`. So this is why you can't find it in the php source git.

Comment: @OfirBaruch You are not mistaken. `sybase_ct` is not in the PHP Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code [can be found here](https://github.com/thekid/php-src/tree/master/ext/sybase_ct) on GitHub. This is the maintainer's fork.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/0676f39ee4f062da47255e3f477fa9857d2a0b52/EXTENSIONS

Which listed:

```
EXTENSION:           sybase_ct
PRIMARY MAINTAINER:  Timm Friebe <thekid@thekid.de>
MAINTENANCE:         Maintained
STATUS:              Working
```

So I googled Timm Friebe and saw that he had a forked version of the php code with the sybase_ct extension there.